# How do you turn water white?

Tags: water, container

I put beautiful  bottles out with colored water as part of my decorations for each holiday. I can't figure out how to make white so I  can have red white & blue for the 4th of July. Does anyone have any idea''s how to turn water white?

Comment: Hi Sherrie, Welcome to Lifehacks.StackExchange. We hope you enjoy sharing knowledge and experience here.

Comment: Do you have any pictures of past holidays using white and what problem(s) you had? Must the decorations last a certain time?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to color water milky/white, - non-molding, non-sinking?](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/13529/how-to-color-water-milky-white-non-molding-non-sinking)

Comment: What does wAyer mean?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I changed "waYer" to "water", because I think that's what the O.P. meant.

Answer (score 4):

First, the bad news—As there is no white dye, using a pigment is the only practical "solution" to the question. The problem with pigments is that they will settle to the bottom ultimately.

However, the "Wilton" company makes, and markets baking materials and supplies. One of their products for whitening icing, butter, and edibles is a food colouring "whitener" made from titanium dioxide. It is not organic and non toxic since it is made for human consumption. Finely ground TiO<sub>2</sub> should stay in solution for quite a while before settling. The reviews for it are all positive.

Wilton 603-1236 Liquid Color, 2-Ounce, White
[Wilton Canada > Ingredients > Colours and Accents](https://www.amazon.ca/stores/page/A01A1AF7-8A15-4EAE-BD46-D6016EBFAF60?ingress=2&visitId=228df97b-41d2-41e2-ace7-ada3ef81da99&ref_=bl_dp_s_web_11992187011)

[image: White-White Icing Color]

Although it was made to use in baking, it is a water-based liquid concentrate which should satisfy your requirements for display decoration.

Good luck

<sub>Disclaimer: I not affiliated with the product or its sales in any way. I have no interest in this product beyond it being of possible benefit to the individual asking a question on StackExchange.</sub>

Answer (score 3):

I can think of a few options. Some of them may not work for you, depending on how you're using them. (For example, putting milk in a bottle may be a bad idea if it's out in the sun all day.)

1. Use milk instead of water.
2. Add just a bit of milk to the water.
3. Add some white, water-based paint to the water.
4. Instead of water, fill the bottle with a white non-liquid like white rice, white sand, or even shredded or crumpled paper.
5. Paint the outside of the bottle white, instead of relying on the color of the liquid inside.
6. Paint the inside of the bottle white.

Comment: The milk might not be a long-lasting *solution* for it. In my case, it turned greenish after a while.